# Group drugs together when dates overlap

Tags: r, data-manipulation, overlapping

This is a bit tricky to explain so please bear with me and ask questions if I am not making sense.

Here is my data

```
mydata <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                    drug = c("let", "per", "pac", "tra","chem", "tem", "cap", "nem"),
                    type = c("type1", "type2", "type1","type1","type1", "type2", "type1", "type2"), 
                    startdate = c("2016-05-12","2016-05-30","2016-05-31","2016-05-31",  "2018-01-18","2018-04-01", "2020-11-05","2020-11-04"),   
                    enddate =c("2016-05-12", "2018-04-05","2017-11-08", "2018-04-05", "2018-01-18", "2020-11-06", "2021-08-18", "2021-08-11"))
```

My goal is to group the drugs whose dates overlap with each other. But even if there is an overlap with dates between two drugs, but the type of drug switches to type2, I want that to trigger another row with its own start and end dates.

I was able to achieve grouping dates overlapping with each other using the following code

```
mydata <-  mydata %>%
  arrange(id, startdate,drug) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(indx = c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(lead(startdate)) >
                              cummax(as.numeric(enddate)))[-n()])) %>%
  group_by(id, indx) %>%
  mutate(drugs = paste0(drug, collapse = ", "))%>%
  summarise(startDate = min(startdate), endDate = max(enddate), drugs=drugs) %>% distinct()
```

But as you can see after drug "let"; all other rows get grouped together. Where instead I want a new row for "tem" and "nem" as they are type 2 drugs.

This is the output I am hoping to get

```
mydata1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1),
                     drugs = c("let", "per,pac,tra,chem", "tem", "cap, nem"),
                    startdate = c("2016-05-12","2016-05-30","2018-04-01","2020-11-04"),   
                    enddate =c("2016-05-12","2018-01-18", "2020-11-06","2021-08-11"))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Was there a mistake in either mydata1 or mydata? 
I am assuming you don't want per and and pac grouped together because per is a type 2 drug and pac is a type 1 drug, so I'm a bit confused why they are grouped together in mydata1.

Comment: Hey! I do want them together. I was hoping to group together any dates that overlap with each other. But in instances where there are two type 2 drugs in one "group" I wanted that to be a new row

Answer (score 0):

I split the dataframe into separate dataframes for each drug and then used your existing code. Then I put the two new dataframes back together into one dataframe.

I was also getting NA by conversion from the dates, so I converted the dates using lubridate.

```
#change dates to the Date format
require(lubridate)

mydata$startdate <- as.Date(mydata$startdate)
mydata$enddate <- as.Date(mydata$enddate)


# create two seperate dataframes, one for each drug type
type1 <- mydata %>%
  filter(type == "type1")


type2 <- mydata %>%
  filter(type == "type2")


#use your code on both the dataframes

type1_grouped <-type1 %>%
  arrange(id, startdate,drug) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(indx = c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(lead(startdate)) > cummax(as.numeric(enddate)))[-n()])) %>%
  group_by(id, indx) %>%
  mutate(drugs = paste0(drug, collapse = ", "))%>%
  summarise(startDate = min(startdate), endDate = max(enddate), drugs=drugs) %>%
  distinct()

type2_grouped <- type2 %>%
  arrange(id, startdate,drug) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(indx = c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(lead(startdate)) > cummax(as.numeric(enddate)))[-n()])) %>%
  group_by(id, indx) %>%
  mutate(drugs = paste0(drug, collapse = ", "))%>%
  summarise(startDate = min(startdate), endDate = max(enddate), drugs=drugs) %>%
  distinct()
 
 
 

 
# put the two dataframes back together
mydata2 <- rbind(type1_grouped,type2_grouped)
 

# Change the format to match mydata1
mydata2 %>% relocate(drugs, .before=startDate) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-indx)
```